# 3ds max renders background only

Tags: 3dsmax

I have created a scene in 3ds max, imported several objects, added materials and lights and did some low resolution renderings for adjusting. So far so good. 
But suddenly when I start rendering again, 3ds max does not render any object in the scene, but only the background. 
If I select all objects and render "selected" it works. But what have I done wrong, that I cannot just render the viewport as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Many possibilities, let me try to remember some (apart you didn't say which version you're using). Select your objects, then right click'em:

freeze: OFF
hidden: OFF
render: ON
exclude: OFF
receive illumination: ON

On the modifier panel, at right, maybe one object at a time: generate mapping coordenates: ON

With your light(s) selected, same "modifier" panel: verify if the intensity is more than zero, also verify if the light is ON. Verify if there are some aspect, like a bitmap projection not found, or if it's a light exclusive for the use of one render (like Vray special light) at the same time you're not using Vray as your render on "assign render", on your render options.

On your render options: verify if you're rendering a view, which view, or region area, confim if those are what yow want. Verify which render engine youre using and if its not confliting with your light system (brazil light only works with brazil render, Vray the same, and so on).

Verify if your global illumination is not zero. Verify on your backgroud settings if your not using logarithm ilumination.